# WIX - Start programm after rollback

Tags: c#, wix

I have an WIX-Installer. In case an error appears during an update installation, a rollback script is executed.

I want to restart the program after the rollback is finished.

I tried using `CustomActions`, but I think it is not possible to execute them after the `rollback` is finished and the files from the backup are back in there folders.

Does some one have an idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Read this article: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm

Rollback scripts are scheduled as part of the sequence then when an error occurs the sequence is executed in reverse triggering all of the rollback actions.  One of these actions can be a custom action to (re)start your program.

Comment: Hello, the page says:
"Deferred, rollback and commit custom actions can only be placed between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize. Not following this rule will result in error 2762: "Cannot write script record. Transaction not started."

Installfinalize is finished before the backup files are copied to the target location. So if I try to start it in there, the files wouldn't be in the folder.

Comment: All the actions scheduled between InstallIInitialize and InstallFinalize execute inside InstallFinalize in a second pass.  If the rollback is scheduled right after InstallInitialize then everything should be in the state that it started and your program available to be called.  Exception to this would be a Major Upgrade with RemoveExistingProducts scheduled prior to InstallInitialize.  In that case nothing would be installed and the program couldn't be started.